# What is the significance of The Master crossing the river?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-strain

In pilot episode of [The Strain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Strain_%28TV_series%29), [Night Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Zero_%28The_Strain%29), Eichhorst is absolutely insistent that Miguel must "cross the river before dawn". Similarly when he arrives at the airport, Setrakian is absolutely insistent that Dr. Ephraim Goodweather must make sure the box "does not cross the river".

I know that as The Master is some kind of vampire he's vulnerable to sunlight, however if it was just about having him safe by daylight then it wouldn't matter exactly where it was, as long as it was dark enough.

With this in mind, my question is what is the significance of crossing the river, bearing in mind that Setrakian knows this is the plan before having any contact with Eichhorst?

Comment: Vampires having a problem with "Running water" is [a trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CannotCrossRunningWater) that [some stories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vampire_traits_in_folklore_and_fiction#Weaknesses) use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a reference to Dracula by Bram Stocker:

> It is said, too, that he can only pass running water at the slack or the flood of tide.

-Professor Van Helsing in Mina Harker's Journal, Chapter XVIII of Dracula by Bram Stoker

> The Count, even if he takes the form of a bat, cannot cross the running water of his own volition, and so he cannot leave the ship.

-Professor Van Helsing in Jonathan Harker's Journal, Chapter XXV of Dracula by Bram Stoker